# Rate limiting a CoreBluetooth write without response

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm sending a large binary to a BLE device over CoreBluetooth to update the firmware on the device. However, I've run into an issue where CoreBluetooth is not rate limiting the writes and is sending the messages too quickly for the device to receive them all. What is the best way to make sure CoreBluetooth waits long enough so that I make sure all messages are sent (without freezing UI queue)?

My current code is:

```swift
    private func sendOTAUpgrade(data: [UInt8], complete: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let packets = makePackets(size: 20, arr: data)
        var count = 0
        
        for packet in packets {
            firmwareUpgradePercentComplete = Double(count)/Double(packets.count)
            print("Sent packet - \(firmwareUpgradePercentComplete*100)% complete")
            let data = NSData(bytes: packet, length: 20)
            self.connectedPeripheral?.writeValue(data as Data, for: self.otcDataCharacteristic!, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)
            count += 1
        }
        
        complete()
    }
```

Comment: The answer to this is "write with response" and have the firmware provide responses when it's ready for more data. If you're not able to do that, then you're going to have to limit yourself. That'll means some amount of `asyncAfter` calls, or `sleep` calls if you're on your own thread, or whatever kind of pauses you want to put in by whatever mechanism you like. But if your question is how to handle this *using BLE*, the answer is "use responses; that's what they're for." (Alternately, implement flow control over BLE, if you control the firmware.)

Comment: Even better, if your device can support it, use an L2Cap channel.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple ways of doing it. If you want to stick with `.withoutResponse` you should check against `canSendWriteWithoutResponse`, if this property is true you can write again. If it's false you need to wait until `peripheralIsReady` is getting called.

With that you should be able write some data reliable.

Transcript What's new in CoreBluetooth WWDC 2017 Session

> For this year, we've enhanced CBPeripheral with a new property called
> canSendWriteWithoutResponse.
>
> So if you call this before you do a write and it and it returns yes,
> that's our promise to you that your data will not be dropped in
> software before we get a chance to send it to the remote peripheral.
>
> If that returns no, you'll also get a delegate callback when we're
> ready and we'll call back peripheralIsReady

Depending what your goal is you might need to implement some flow control into your peripheral. If this is not possible there might be a pragmatic solution to check how many data your device can handle. So a queue can help here to get some control when sending without having to switch to .writeWithResponse

Answer (score 0):

Do write without response, include sequence index number with each central write, and have peripheral after it receives each write send back a notify that contains state of transmission, ie. echo back latest sequence num OR seq num out of order error. After central sends final write, it awaits seq num of final write from peripheral.